# 3 rows, 100% height flexbox layout doesn't work on android

Tags: css, html, sass, flexbox

please take a look:

https://jsfiddle.net/sgtooLnb/1/

so basically a flexbox column layout and an html structure like this (I must add some more code for the parser..):

```
<header>The header content goes here.</header>
<div class="content">The main content goes here.</div>
<footer>The footer content goes here.</footer>
```

On android (4.4.2), a layout like this seems not to work. Footer will always stick on bottom, while overflowing content will be below the footer.

Sadly, you cannot see this behavour from jsfiddle, but maybe some of you have had the same problem before.

Any solution?

Comment: try changing the body to `min-height`

Comment: what is your complete code (with html, head, body... tags)?

Comment: First, you should not post yet another question which is pretty much the exact same as the previous. I also recommend to close this as a dupe in favor of your previous question, and if you want, you post your answer there instead. I also posted an answer at the other that both cover the Android fix and IE fix.

Comment: First, it's not the same. Second, I couldn't since it was blocked. Third, your solution is not for body container, thus is not a solution. Fourth, my solution  works, read it, along with the external documentation I originally provided and the IE variant. Or just use Autoprefixer, as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, by better indagating [this](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/) and [this](https://github.com/philipwalton/solved-by-flexbox/blob/master/assets/css/components/site.css) I found out that the problem is [this](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#1-minimum-content-sizing-of-flex-items-not-honored) even if Android is not mentioned on the affected browsers list. So, my solution was to add flex-shrink: 0 to the content:

```
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content{
  flex: 1 0 auto; // flex-shrink:0 > android 4.4.2 fix (and some other browsers too)
}
```

It's also good to assign some kind of flex property to header and footer. I noticed on Android 442 that otherwise the bg color was gone:

```
.main-header,
.main-footer{
    flex: none; // or flex something.
}
```

Also please note that I'm using Autoprefixer. Otherwise, you should not use the shortcut on main-content (IE shit-fix):

```
.main-content{
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-basis:auto;
}
```

Finally, to the one that downvoted this thread: you had the relevant code on the jsfiddle. Also, if you really knew the subject, you didn't need any code. And if you didn't know the subject, you shouldn't downvote anything.
Now please downvote again, so this material won't help anyone. Is this the main stackoverflow target?

Comment: Does this work on Android 4.4.2? https://jsfiddle.net/4c3gk4ax/2/ ... both as a sticky footer and when content overflows?

Comment: This solution will work with IE11 as well as android 4.4.2. Also, I'm curretly using android 4.4.2, just as a lot of friends of mine: not all the people is constantly spending their money to get a new phone when the current works just good.

Comment: Here is 2 versions of your suggested solution, both using Autoprefixer, one with little content, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRVZxj, one with much content, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apVNYp Are both these according to the correct solution that works both with Android and IE?

Answer (score 0):

The children elements of your flex element (`body`) need to be `display: flex` as well. If you add the style

```
body > * {
    display: flex;
}
```

I believe you'll get the desired result